# Unsatisfied Link Error and missing .so files when starting Eclipse

Tags: 12.04, java, eclipse

I upgraded to the 12.04 beta yesterday. Now, when I try to start Eclipse, I get the splash screen and then this error message:

```
An error has occurred. See the log file /home/gabriel/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/configuration/1335382319394.log .
```

The log file says something like this:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    no swt-gtk-3740 in java.library.path
    no swt-gtk in java.library.path
    Can't load library: /home/gabriel/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-3740.so
    Can't load library: /home/gabriel/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk.so
```

followed by many more error messages.

The `/home/gabriel/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/` directory exists, but is empty. I also tried reinstalling eclipse with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a bug. Please log into Launchpad and register that this also affects you: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse/+bug/989615

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have got the same issue in an AMD64 machine (Ubuntu 12.04). and solved it by a workaround:

**copy: files containing '3740' in**  /usr/lib/jni/libswt-*3740.so **to** ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/

But, be sure the packages : **libswt-gtk-3-java** & **libswt-gtk-3-jni** are installed.

```
sudo apt-get install libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-gtk-3-java
```

And

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/jni/libswt-*3740.so ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/
```

if you have a 32 bits based system :
  `sudo cp /usr/lib/jni/libswt-*3740.so ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86`/

Comment: wow this actually worked for me too (Intel core i5, 64 bit ubuntu 12.04) thanks a lot!

Comment: Worked great for a 32-bit system. Using: `sudo cp /usr/lib/jni/libswt-*3740.so ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/` . Thanks and update your answer please.

Comment: It really works for me either (Ubuntu precise 64 bit). I had created soft links instead of copy.

Answer (score 4):

Try running

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

and selection `open jdk`. This would probably work.

Comment: This did work, but I'm trying to avoid using `openjdk`.

Comment: Actually, never mind. I'll just go with it.

Comment: I also wanted to avoid openjdk, so check out Hanynowsky's answer; it worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Also for me it works; I done:

```
cd ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-atk-gtk-3740.so
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-gtk-3740.so
ln-s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-pi-gtk-3740.so
```

and so, I created 3 symlink in the folder ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64

Now Eclipse works fine!

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni" >> /etc/eclipse.ini
```

fixed it for me.

Comment: Love this solution, fixed it for all users.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the great instructions. I added symlinks like this instead, to make sure it picks up all *3740*:

```
cd ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64

for i in /usr/lib/jni/*3740*.so ; do ln -s $i; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I made symlinks to the missing libs and everything worked fine. It ended up looking like this...

```
    libswt-atk-gtk-3740.so -> /usr/lib/jni/libswt-atk-gtk-3740.so
    libswt-gtk-3740.so -> /usr/lib/jni/libswt-gtk-3740.so
    libswt-pi-gtk-3740.so -> /usr/lib/jni/libswt-pi-gtk-3740.so
```

Seems to work.