# Eclipse isn't working after upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unsatisfied Link Error and missing .so files when starting Eclipse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125150/unsatisfied-link-error-and-missing-so-files-when-starting-eclipse)

after i've upgraded my ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 eclipse fail to launch and gives me an error message telling me to see the log file. Here's the log file

```
!SESSION 2012-04-28 17:24:33.607 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.7.0
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-04-28 17:24:35.779
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
no swt-gtk-3740 in java.library.path
no swt-gtk in java.library.path
Can't load library: /home/leo/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-gtk-3740.so
Can't load library: /home/leo/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-gtk.so

at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:285)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:194)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:695)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:153)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:95)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```