# Eclipse won't work in 12.04 64 bit

Tags: eclipse

I just finished upgrading my ubuntu

I had eclipse installed from terminal using apt-get install eclipse

Now I'm getting the following error

> An error has occurred. See the log file
>   /home/toluwanimi/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/configuration/1336830746877.log.

Please how do I go fix this

I've tried most of the fixes on this site but they don't seem to work for me

Here's the log

```
!SESSION 2012-05-12 14:52:26.563 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.7.0_02
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_GB
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-05-12 14:52:29.469
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
        no swt-gtk-3740 in java.library.path
        no swt-gtk in java.library.path
        Can't load library: /home/toluwanimi/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-3740.so
        Can't load library: /home/toluwanimi/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk.so

        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:285)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:194)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:695)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:153)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java1386)
```

Comment: What is in the log file?

Comment: wait a second..

Comment: Make sure you have 64 bit Eclipse and 64 bit java or 32 bit Eclipse and 32 bit java as suggested here: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=663734

Comment: @desgua you should propose your comment as a potential answer :)

Comment: I had the same problem , see http://askubuntu.com/a/128263/4937

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unsatisfied Link Error and missing .so files when starting Eclipse](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125150/unsatisfied-link-error-and-missing-so-files-when-starting-eclipse)

Answer (score 3):

have you installed different versions of java rather than 1.7.x? it may be confused to eclipse, just see this link to re-configure your java environment.

To fix, open up terminal and type

sudo update-alternatives --config java

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165693/ubuntu-eclipse-cannot-load-swt-libraries-not-opening

In addition, I recommend install java and eclipse with self-extract files, it's easy to re-configure and can have multiple versions of them. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, I have 3 java alternatives - switching to another as the preferred on worked - Thanks all

Comment: yeah, also , keep in mind that you can put a 32bit jdk on 64 bit linux and also run the 32bit eclipse.   that is what I do.  of course, you have to fiddle with alternatives to make that work though.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-atk-gtk-3740.so
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-gtk-3740.so
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-pi-gtk-3740.so
```

I created three symlinks in the folder `~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64`

Now Eclipse is working.

Answer (score -2):

Try with this command:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/
```

Comment: What is supposed to do this?